# Rendering the state value in the input field in React Redux makes the value unchangable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-state-management

I am developing a Web Application using React and Redux. I am new to React and Redux. Now, I am having an issue using it together, React and Redux. The problem is  I cannot change the input field value when I set the value of the field with the state value.

In my component, I have a property called, event in the state which is coming from connect like this.

```
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    return {
        submittingForm : state.editEvent.submittingForm,
        formErrors : state.editEvent.formErrors,
        event: state.editEvent.event,
    };
}
```

As you can see the event filed is coming from the reducer. In my component, I can retrieve the event like this.

```
this.props.event.name
```

Now, what I am trying to do is when I edit the event, I like to maintain the values of the event in the input field.

Therefore, I render the  state value in the input field like this.

```
<TextField
      name="location"
      label="Location"
      value={this.props.event? this.props.event.location: ""} />
```

It is maintaining the value in the input field. But the problem is I cannot change the input field now. I can focus on the text input field, but when I type in anything using keyboards, the value is not changing and just keeps displaying the state value. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Where are you listening to the input typing?

Comment: You need to set an `onChange` event in your `TextField` component that dispatches an action to update the proper reducer or that modifies the local state of the component.

Comment: @Dez Thank you for the suggestion. That is annoying pattern (Redux).

Comment: Hi, it is working. But it is very slow. While I was typing in on the text field, I can see the lagging because I think react is continuously updating the DOM. Is there a better way to do it, please?

Answer (score 0):

If it is slow, I would use something like `debounce` function (see here: https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce). Essentially, it is useful, when you have groups of often events, and you want to call some function, only when there is a certain timeout elapsed since the last event.

So, instead of emitting a new event every time something is changed, you can emit it only after 300-500ms after user finished typing. This looks like batching of all the changes into a single update. If this is something acceptable for your problem, here is how you can do it:

```
var debouncedOnChange = _.debounce(current_onChange_method, 300 or another time in ms);
```

Then in `<TextField>` set `onChange` to `debouncedOnChange`.